# What should I use Arduino-Mega or Rasbeery pi?

Tags: arduino-mega

I am doing a project on Vehicle tracking and security. In my project Micro controller will sense input from sensors and at the same time it has to sense signal from user for tracking purpose and continuously checking the speed limit and boundary. so, there will be 3-4 tasks that would be executing parallel. Can anyone suggest which one is perfect for this kind of project... Arduino-Mega or Rasberry Pi?

Comment: there are many other options.

Comment: beery pi are more fun

Comment: What are the readout from sensors? If any of them is video, go for PI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RaspberryPi is essentially a small, low-spec computer. It is mostly an overkill for many small projects. Imagine using a super high-spec computer to play Minecraft. It's just nonsensical.

I'm assuming you'll be connecting to the car battery? Take note of the power requirements of your project. The RaspberryPi has a power requirement of [2.1A at 5V](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/) (which is a lot!), whilst an Arduino has a minimum requirement of [250mA](https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/WhatAdapter).

Also remember: the RaspberryPi is running an operating system in the background in order to run your code. It will be working on numerous other operations and programs, not just yours. The Arduino will only run your program.

I had a similar project to what it sounds like you're doing. I used an Arduino Mega and had Bluetooth, GPS, and SD card all connected to it. The project worked absolutely fine, and I had lots of spare program space left over should I wish to expand on it. For reference, [feel free to explore](https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Telematics-Box/).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply and suggestion. Your are absolutely right about the power requirements but the thing that I am concerned about is that can Arduino run parallel tasks like I mention there's been a request for a location at the same time sensing data from vibration sensor and check for specified boundary or speed...... so can arduino handle all tasks at same time?

Comment: In short, multithreading is not support on the Arduino. There are [libraries](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/reanimationxp/how-to-multithread-an-arduino-protothreading-tutorial-dd2c37) that can supposedly do it, but all they do is slow down the program. Arduinos work synchronously (lines of code are executed one after the other, never simultaneously), so you would have to design your program to run synchronously.

Comment: you could use a dual-core ESP32 to do 2 things at once, and the ESP does them WAY WAY faster than a mega, which cuts down on opportunities for conflict. it's also cheaper and smaller.

Comment: so you mean ESP32 can run tasks(more than 2) simultaneously ?